# Writing a Linux compatible kernel

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, operating-system

I saw list of Linux system calls here:
http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/
If I write a new kernel that implements all these system calls that are listed in the above link, can the kernel run all the programs compiled for Linux?
Will it be Linux compatible?

Comment: It will be able to run Linux programs but typical Linux programs expect more than just a bunch of system calls to be present. Getting full Linux compatibility is much more work.

Comment: @fuz What are the other things that a typical Linux program expects? Is it possible to implement them?

Comment: A dynamic loader, a bunch of shared libraries, a bunch of configuration files, localization data, etc etc. You can't really implement these things as they are marginally standardized and very complex but you can take them and place them on your system for (Linux) programs to use.

Comment: Linux compiled executable are in ELF format. So the kernel you are designing should recognise it.

Comment: I suggest you design something new instead, whether you are doing it for fun, whether you are doing it to have it used. In the former case, writing a Linux-compatible kernel takes out all the fun. In the latter case, consider that Linux already has a 25+ years headstart. Of course, however, it is just my opinion and I know many (most?) people will disagree with me, but to have a wider perspective, you need to be aware of both sides.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *a single linux syscall* is more than a (sane) single person would voluntarily reimplement: `ioctl`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can the kernel run all the programs

*By itself* **kernel** can ... **nothing useful**.

You need *Operating system* (OS) for run programs and do other usual things. Aside from kernel, OS consist of dynamic loader, (standard) libraries, (standard) utilities and many other things.

However, you may use your kernel with Linux operating system. (That is what "rebuilding the kernel" means: replace the kernel, but remain other OS components the same).

Bad thing is that, aside from system calls, **kernel should contain drivers**, both for hardware (video card, hard drive, and so on) and for software (like filesystems, which are implemented by Linux in the kernel). Drivers are needed for boot on any computer, output to the monitor, read programs from the disk, etc.

Also, system calls are not the only interface between Linux kernel and user space. For make you kernel work with Linux OS you need to provide **special filesystems** like `sysfs`: many Linux utilities and programs expect to find appropriate files here.

Comment: yep, take a look at all the stuff under /proc and /sys, just for starters; you get to reimplement most or all of that, too.

Comment: Thanks for all the help...I have decided not to make it Linux compatible...I agree with @glauxosdever